# How do you find the absolute maximum and minimum of the function "z"?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, maxima-minima

$f(z)$ = $\sin x  + \sin y + \sin (x+y)$ in the region $0 ≤ x ≤ \frac{π}{2}$ , $0 ≤ y ≤ \frac{π}{2}$

> What is the best way to resolve this issue?

Should I take the first derivative, find the zeros, and test the value of the function against the other points?

Comment: Take derivatives with respect to $x$ and $y$. You also need to check the boundaries.

Comment: You need to define the relationship between z and the other variables.